# Detect backward/pop navigation in destination view controller viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

There are a number of well known solutions for detecting when a view controller is in the process of disappearing off the screen in the process of a backwards navigation, managed by a `UINavigationController` (i.e. when a view controller is being popped off the navigation stack). In other words detecting a backwards navigation within the source view controller.

In contrast, I need to detect a backwards navigation within `viewWillAppear` for the *destination* view controller. Or to put it another way, detect when a view controller is about to be displayed as a result of a `UINavigationController` pop.

What is the cleanest/simplest way to achieve this? Implementing `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and setting a flag might be one approach, but would rather avoid mutable state if possible.

I am not using Storyboards to manage the transition between these two screens.

Comment: Detecting those property `isMovingToParentViewController` or `isMovingFromParentViewController`  in `viewWillAppear:` may help.

Comment: Thanks - I can confirm this works in `viewWillAppear`:  `if !isMovingToParentViewController { print("backwards") }`
If you post again as an answer, I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this property of UIViewController :P

[isMovingToParentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2097561-ismovingtoparentviewcontroller)

[isMovingFromParentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2097565-ismovingfromparentviewcontroller)